# highcharts not refreshing chart when page refreshes

Tags: csv, highcharts, refresh

i have created a highchart and data i took it from csv file.The chart is working good and plotting fine.But my problem is when the page refreshes it is not taking the latest value from the csv file.It still displays the old chart.when i close the browser and re-open the chart works fine.Please help me how to reset/redraw with updated value from csv
Below is my code. This problem IE not in firefox

> var options = {
>                     chart: {
>                         renderTo: 'container',
>                         defaultSeriesType: 'line',
>                         marginRight: 130,
>                           marginBottom: 25
>                     },
>                     title: {
>                         text: 'Support Trending P1,P2 & P3'
>                     },
>                     xAxis: {
>                         categories: []
>                     },
>
> ```
>               yAxis: {
>
>                   showLastLabel:true,
>                   tickInterval:5,
>                   title: {
>                           text: ""
>                   }
>                   },
>
>               series: []
>           };
>
>
>           $.get('../data/trending.txt', function(data) {
>               // Split the lines
>               var lines = data.split(';');
>               $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
>                   var items = line.split(',');
>
>                   // header line containes categories
>                   if (lineNo == 0) {
>                       $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
>                           if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
>                       });
>                   }
>
>                   // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
>                   else {
>                       var series = {
>                           data: []
>                       };
>                       $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
>                           if (itemNo == 0) {
>                               series.name = item;
>                           } else {
>                               series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
>                           }
>                       });
>
>                       options.series.push(series);
>
>                   }
>
>               });
>
>               var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
>           });
>
>
>       });
> ```
>
> > Blockquote

Comment: my code:http://jsfiddle.net/r9Afj/4/embedded/result/

Comment: any one knows the answer

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your chart data is being cached, and not being refreshed by the browser. Without code, it's card to know how to fix it.

If you are using jquery $.ajax, there is an option

```
 cache:false
```

Which may help.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Above answer is proper. You should use `$.ajax()` instead of `$.get()`  and set `cache: false`.